# Whitelist home page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using force login wordpress plugin to restrict user to login before viewing certain pages but i want to view home page without login i am trying to add home page in whitelist but its not working i am using my custom theme.Can you suggest what plugin should i use/what should i do for this purpose.

```
function my_forcelogin_whitelist( $whitelist ) {
            //$whitelist[] = 'http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/home/';
            //$whitelist[] = site_url( '/index.php/home/' );
              $whitelist[] = 'http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/';
              $whitelist[] = site_url( '/index.php/' );

        return $whitelist;
    }
    add_filter('v_forcelogin_whitelist', 'my_forcelogin_whitelist', 10, 1);
```

Comment: I think you could probably create your own small plugin that loads after the users "session" is started. Just have your function look at the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI']` (or wordpress equivalent, I am not 100% fluent in WP so here may be a way to natively get this) and first check if user is logged in, then if not, check if user is on one of the whitelisted URLs. I presume you are using the default server rewrite...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code to your theme's functions.php. It will check if you're logged in or not. For next, if current page is not homepage or frontpage, it will redirect user to login page.

And you don't need other plugin to redirect, so please disable any force login plugin before test this code.

```
function logged_in_only() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if( !is_home() || !is_front_page() )
            auth_redirect();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'logged_in_only' );
```

Comment: thanks and if i want to prevent any other page from redirection what should i do??

Comment: Then you can add more condition tags into line 3. More detail about WordPress's condition tags here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags